# how to compare two values and return the correct answer javascript, and how to call a function only once javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I am trying to create a game where you match the last letter of a random country to the first letter of a new country. 
I have all the countries located in an array. I am able to show the random country on the screen but if the person clicks again a new country will appear erasing the old one. 
I want it to only be able to click once and you are stuck with the first country it says.

I am having trouble making the if statements to test if they actually passed all the tests which are

1) Make sure the last letter of random country matches the first letter of the country the user is typing in.

2) Make sure it's actually in the array of countries I have defined.

3) Make sure it's not an empty string

4) Make sure they didn't use that country previously

I know it is a lot to ask but I have been stuck for a while and I could really use the help of someone who has more experience

constructive criticism is highly appreciated if you have any suggestions to make  my code run faster,readable,etc please let me know

thanks in advance

here is an example of my code

```js
function randomCountry () {
  var tries = 0;
  var temp = country[sr];
  var input = document.getElementById("random-country").value
  var val = document.getElementById("gues").value
  var sr = Math.floor(Math.random()*256)
  var startCountry = document.getElementById("random-country").innerHTML = country[sr];
}

function enterCountry () {
var val = document.getElementById("gues").value
var node = document.createElement("LI").value
var textNode = document.createTextNode(val)
var a = document.body.appendChild(textNode).value;
var temp = country[sr];
var sr = Math.floor(Math.random()*256)
var startCountry = document.getElementById("random-country").value
alert(startCountry)
alert(val)
if(startCountry.substr(startCountry.length - 1) === val.substr(val.length - 0)) {
alert("correct")
} else  {
alert("incorrect")
}
}
// it is getting the value from the id at line 14 

function newGame()
 {
 
  if(window.confirm("Do you want to start a new game?"))
  {
 
     window.location.reload();  /* reloads the page for a new game */
 
     document.form1.hint.value = "Enter your guess below and click on Guess!";
 
  }
 
 }

// var le = country.length;

var country = [
"Afghanistan",
"Akrotiri",
"Albania",
"Algeria",
"American Samoa",
"Andorra",
"Angola",
"Anguilla",
"Antarctica",
"Antigua and Barbuda",
"Argentina",
"Armenia",
"Aruba",
"Ashmore and Cartier Islands",
"Australia",
"Austria",
"Azerbaijan",
"Bahamas The",
"Bahrain",
"Bangladesh",
"Barbados",
"Bassas da India",
"Belarus",
"Belgium",
"Belize",
"Benin",
"Bermuda",
"Bhutan",
"Bolivia",
"Bosnia and Herzegovina",
"Botswana",
"Bouvet Island",
"Brazil",
"British Indian Ocean Territory",
"British Virgin Islands",
"Brunei",
"Bulgaria",
"Burkina Faso",
"Burma",
"Burundi",
"Cambodia",
"Cameroon",
"Canada",
"Cape Verde",
"Cayman Islands",
"Central African Republic",
"Chad",
"Chile",
"China",
"Christmas Island",
"Clipperton Island",
"Cocos Islands",
"Colombia",
"Comoros",
"Democratic Republic of the Congo",
"Republic of the Congo",
"Cook Islands",
"Coral Sea Islands",
"Costa Rica",
"Cote d Ivoire",
"Croatia",
"Cuba",
"Cyprus",
"Czech Republic",
"Denmark",
"Dhekelia",
"Djibouti",
"Dominica",
"Dominican Republic",
"Ecuador",
"Egypt",
"El Salvador",
"Equatorial Guinea",
"Eritrea",
"Estonia",
"Ethiopia",
"Europa Island",
"Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)",
"Faroe Islands",
"Fiji",
"Finland",
"France",
"French Guiana",
"French Polynesia",
"French Southern and Antarctic Lands",
"Gabon",
"Gambia",
"Gaza Strip",
"Georgia",
"Germany",
"Ghana",
"Gibraltar",
"Glorioso Islands",
"Greece",
"Greenland",
"Grenada",
"Guadeloupe",
"Guam",
"Guatemala",
"Guernsey",
"Guinea",
"Guinea Bissau",
"Guyana",
"Haiti",
"Heard Island and McDonald Islands",
"Vatican City",
"Honduras",
"Hong Kong",
"Hungary",
"Iceland",
"India",
"Indonesia",
"Iran",
"Iraq",
"Ireland",
"Isle of Man",
"Israel",
"Italy",
"Jamaica",
"Jan Mayen",
"Japan",
"Jersey",
"Jordan",
"Juan de Nova Island",
"Kazakhstan",
"Kenya",
"Kiribati",
"North Korea",
"South Korea",
"Kuwait",
"Kyrgyzstan",
"Laos",
"Latvia",
"Lebanon",
"Lesotho",
"Liberia",
"Libya",
"Liechtenstein",
"Lithuania",
"Luxembourg",
"Macau",
"Macedonia",
"Madagascar",
"Malawi",
"Malaysia",
"Maldives",
"Mali",
"Malta",
"Marshall Islands",
"Martinique",
"Mauritania",
"Mauritius",
"Mayotte",
"Mexico",
"Micronesia",
"Moldova",
"Monaco",
"Mongolia",
"Montserrat",
"Morocco",
"Mozambique",
"Namibia",
"Nauru",
"Navassa Island",
"Nepal",
"Netherlands",
"Netherlands Antilles",
"New Caledonia",
"New Zealand",
"Nicaragua",
"Niger",
"Nigeria",
"Niue",
"Norfolk Island",
"Northern Mariana Islands",
"Norway",
"Oman",
"Pakistan",
"Palau",
"Panama",
"Papua New Guinea",
"Paracel Islands",
"Paraguay",
"Peru",
"Philippines",
"Pitcairn Islands",
"Poland",
"Portugal",
"Puerto Rico",
"Qatar",
"Reunion",
"Romania",
"Russia",
"Rwanda",
"Saint Helena",
"Saint Kitts and Nevis",
"Saint Lucia",
"Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
"Samoa",
"San Marino",
"Sao Tome and Principe",
"Saudi Arabia",
"Senegal",
"Serbia and Montenegro",
"Seychelles",
"Sierra Leone",
"Singapore",
"Slovakia",
"Slovenia",
"Solomon Islands",
"Somalia",
"South Africa",
"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
"Spain",
"Spratly Islands",
"Sri Lanka",
"Sudan",
"Suriname",
"Svalbard",
"Swaziland",
"Sweden",
"Switzerland",
"Syria",
"Taiwan",
"Tajikistan",
"Tanzania",
"Thailand",
"Timor-Leste",
"Togo",
"Tokelau",
"Tonga",
"Trinidad and Tobago",
"Tromelin Island",
"Tunisia",
"Turkey",
"Turkmenistan",
"Turks and Caicos Islands",
"Tuvalu",
"Uganda",
"Ukraine",
"United Arab Emirates",
"United Kingdom",
"United States",
"Uruguay",
"Uzbekistan",
"Vanuatu",
"Venezuela",
"Vietnam",
"Virgin Islands",
"Wake Island",
"Wallis and Futuna",
"West Bank",
"Western Sahara",
"Yemen",
"Zambia",
"Zimbabwe"
]



// var sr = Math.Floor(Math.Random() *180)
// var temp = country[sr]
// var tries= 0
// var country = newArray(180)
```

```css
body {
 
}

button {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}

div {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>The Country Game</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h3>Welcome to my first game!</h3>
     <h4>How to play</h4>
     <button id="random-country" onClick="randomCountry()" type="button" value="randomCountry()">Click me to start!</button>
     <p>Match the last letter of the country shown above to the first letter of a new country that has not been named yet. </p>
     <div id="guess">
         <ul id="guesses">
             <li>
             <li>
                 
             </li>
         </li>
         </ul>
         <input id="gues" type="text" placeholder="enter here">
         </div>
     <form>
  <button id="answer" onClick="enterCountry()" type="button">Enter Country</button>
  <button id="new-game" onClick="newGame()" type="button">New Game</button>
  <button id="list-eraser" onClick="eraseList()" type="button">Erase List</button>

  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Edit 2

You never have to saved the random value in a variable outside the scope of the function, and you were reasing it each time, so you will never get the value.

I changed the scope of the variable like this:

```
var startCountry
    function randomCountry () {
      var tries = 0;
      var temp = country[sr];
      var input = document.getElementById("random-country").value
      var val = document.getElementById("gues").value
      var sr = Math.floor(Math.random()*256)
      startCountry = document.getElementById("random-country").innerHTML = country[sr];
    }
```

And then changed the other function to just uuse the variable, and not reasing it:

```
function enterCountry () {
var val = document.getElementById("gues").value
var node = document.createElement("LI").value
var textNode = document.createTextNode(val)
var a = document.body.appendChild(textNode).value;
var temp = country[sr];
var sr = Math.floor(Math.random()*256)
alert(startCountry)
alert(val)
if(startCountry.toUpperCase().substr(startCountry.length - 1) === val.toUpperCase().substr(0,1)) {
alert("correct")
} else  {
alert("incorrect")
}
}
```

And If you want to compare the last latter of the random country and the first one of the typed country, you could do this:

```
if(startCountry.substr(startCountry.length - 1) === val.charAt(0))
```

> Finally the code bellow all together works:

```js
var startCountry
function randomCountry () {
  var tries = 0;
  var temp = country[sr];
  var input = document.getElementById("random-country").value
  var val = document.getElementById("gues").value
  var sr = Math.floor(Math.random()*256)
  startCountry = document.getElementById("random-country").innerHTML = country[sr];
}

function enterCountry () {
var val = document.getElementById("gues").value
var node = document.createElement("LI").value
var textNode = document.createTextNode(val)
var a = document.body.appendChild(textNode).value;
var temp = country[sr];
var sr = Math.floor(Math.random()*256)
alert(startCountry)
alert(val)
if(startCountry.substr(startCountry.length - 1).toUpperCase() === val.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) {
alert("correct")
} else  {
alert("incorrect")
}
}
// it is getting the value from the id at line 14 

function newGame()
 {
 
  if(window.confirm("Do you want to start a new game?"))
  {
 
     window.location.reload();  /* reloads the page for a new game */
 
     document.form1.hint.value = "Enter your guess below and click on Guess!";
 
  }
 
 }

// var le = country.length;

var country = [
"Afghanistan",
"Akrotiri",
"Albania",
"Algeria",
"American Samoa",
"Andorra",
"Angola",
"Anguilla",
"Antarctica",
"Antigua and Barbuda",
"Argentina",
"Armenia",
"Aruba",
"Ashmore and Cartier Islands",
"Australia",
"Austria",
"Azerbaijan",
"Bahamas The",
"Bahrain",
"Bangladesh",
"Barbados",
"Bassas da India",
"Belarus",
"Belgium",
"Belize",
"Benin",
"Bermuda",
"Bhutan",
"Bolivia",
"Bosnia and Herzegovina",
"Botswana",
"Bouvet Island",
"Brazil",
"British Indian Ocean Territory",
"British Virgin Islands",
"Brunei",
"Bulgaria",
"Burkina Faso",
"Burma",
"Burundi",
"Cambodia",
"Cameroon",
"Canada",
"Cape Verde",
"Cayman Islands",
"Central African Republic",
"Chad",
"Chile",
"China",
"Christmas Island",
"Clipperton Island",
"Cocos Islands",
"Colombia",
"Comoros",
"Democratic Republic of the Congo",
"Republic of the Congo",
"Cook Islands",
"Coral Sea Islands",
"Costa Rica",
"Cote d Ivoire",
"Croatia",
"Cuba",
"Cyprus",
"Czech Republic",
"Denmark",
"Dhekelia",
"Djibouti",
"Dominica",
"Dominican Republic",
"Ecuador",
"Egypt",
"El Salvador",
"Equatorial Guinea",
"Eritrea",
"Estonia",
"Ethiopia",
"Europa Island",
"Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)",
"Faroe Islands",
"Fiji",
"Finland",
"France",
"French Guiana",
"French Polynesia",
"French Southern and Antarctic Lands",
"Gabon",
"Gambia",
"Gaza Strip",
"Georgia",
"Germany",
"Ghana",
"Gibraltar",
"Glorioso Islands",
"Greece",
"Greenland",
"Grenada",
"Guadeloupe",
"Guam",
"Guatemala",
"Guernsey",
"Guinea",
"Guinea Bissau",
"Guyana",
"Haiti",
"Heard Island and McDonald Islands",
"Vatican City",
"Honduras",
"Hong Kong",
"Hungary",
"Iceland",
"India",
"Indonesia",
"Iran",
"Iraq",
"Ireland",
"Isle of Man",
"Israel",
"Italy",
"Jamaica",
"Jan Mayen",
"Japan",
"Jersey",
"Jordan",
"Juan de Nova Island",
"Kazakhstan",
"Kenya",
"Kiribati",
"North Korea",
"South Korea",
"Kuwait",
"Kyrgyzstan",
"Laos",
"Latvia",
"Lebanon",
"Lesotho",
"Liberia",
"Libya",
"Liechtenstein",
"Lithuania",
"Luxembourg",
"Macau",
"Macedonia",
"Madagascar",
"Malawi",
"Malaysia",
"Maldives",
"Mali",
"Malta",
"Marshall Islands",
"Martinique",
"Mauritania",
"Mauritius",
"Mayotte",
"Mexico",
"Micronesia",
"Moldova",
"Monaco",
"Mongolia",
"Montserrat",
"Morocco",
"Mozambique",
"Namibia",
"Nauru",
"Navassa Island",
"Nepal",
"Netherlands",
"Netherlands Antilles",
"New Caledonia",
"New Zealand",
"Nicaragua",
"Niger",
"Nigeria",
"Niue",
"Norfolk Island",
"Northern Mariana Islands",
"Norway",
"Oman",
"Pakistan",
"Palau",
"Panama",
"Papua New Guinea",
"Paracel Islands",
"Paraguay",
"Peru",
"Philippines",
"Pitcairn Islands",
"Poland",
"Portugal",
"Puerto Rico",
"Qatar",
"Reunion",
"Romania",
"Russia",
"Rwanda",
"Saint Helena",
"Saint Kitts and Nevis",
"Saint Lucia",
"Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
"Samoa",
"San Marino",
"Sao Tome and Principe",
"Saudi Arabia",
"Senegal",
"Serbia and Montenegro",
"Seychelles",
"Sierra Leone",
"Singapore",
"Slovakia",
"Slovenia",
"Solomon Islands",
"Somalia",
"South Africa",
"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
"Spain",
"Spratly Islands",
"Sri Lanka",
"Sudan",
"Suriname",
"Svalbard",
"Swaziland",
"Sweden",
"Switzerland",
"Syria",
"Taiwan",
"Tajikistan",
"Tanzania",
"Thailand",
"Timor-Leste",
"Togo",
"Tokelau",
"Tonga",
"Trinidad and Tobago",
"Tromelin Island",
"Tunisia",
"Turkey",
"Turkmenistan",
"Turks and Caicos Islands",
"Tuvalu",
"Uganda",
"Ukraine",
"United Arab Emirates",
"United Kingdom",
"United States",
"Uruguay",
"Uzbekistan",
"Vanuatu",
"Venezuela",
"Vietnam",
"Virgin Islands",
"Wake Island",
"Wallis and Futuna",
"West Bank",
"Western Sahara",
"Yemen",
"Zambia",
"Zimbabwe"
]



// var sr = Math.Floor(Math.Random() *180)
// var temp = country[sr]
// var tries= 0
// var country = newArray(180)
```

```css
body {
 
}

button {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}

div {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>The Country Game</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h3>Welcome to my first game!</h3>
     <h4>How to play</h4>
     <button id="random-country" onClick="randomCountry()" type="button" value="randomCountry()">Click me to start!</button>
     <p>Match the last letter of the country shown above to the first letter of a new country that has not been named yet. </p>
     <div id="guess">
         <ul id="guesses">
             <li>
             <li>
                 
             </li>
         </li>
         </ul>
         <input id="gues" type="text" placeholder="enter here">
         </div>
     <form>
  <button id="answer" onClick="enterCountry()" type="button">Enter Country</button>
  <button id="new-game" onClick="newGame()" type="button">New Game</button>
  <button id="list-eraser" onClick="eraseList()" type="button">Erase List</button>

  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it doesn't work for some reason, I think var startCountry is somehow not carrying the value from random-country. or random-country value is not changing at all

Comment: @user7400006 I know the reason, I'm trying to fix it, I tell you, look, your buttom is not showing the correct country, instead, is shows the value "randomCountry()" when you click it, that's why never match, unless you give a country finishing with "y"

Comment: @user7400006 I added the alerts that will help you to find the bug in your code, check my updated answer

Comment: ah thank you very much i see that the value of the random-country button was calling the randomCountry() function in the HTML

Comment: @user7400006 exactly! don't forget accept the answer if was useful for you :), check box at the left of the anwer ;)

Comment: why does startCountry never have a value? whenever i alert startCountry it always comes back empty, is it because it is button and the other is input tag?

Comment: @user7400006 if you edit your question and put the new code I could see maybe what happens

Comment: @user7400006 I edited the answer, It works just fine now :)

Comment: @user7400006 I added the explaination of what I did, let me know if you understand everything

Comment: brother thank you very much for helping me. you are awesome. now I can try to implement the rest lol. thanks again.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me and yes the explanation help

Comment: @user7400006 oh.. please, I have always loved to help :), no problem at all. I added a little change so you will not have problem with case sensitive, I mean, If your country is Argentina, and then you write Angola, it will give error because "A" is not equal to "a". I fix that